# I need help building an api to connect with another system by .net framework mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

have a project in MVC using .NET Framework v4.7 . What I need to know is how to use a bulding api for integration with other system.
Knowing that the other system gave me all the requirements to connect with it

I've searched everywhere looking for a solution sample, but I couldn't find anything.

If anyone could help, I would be grateful.

Comment: provide more details about *the other system*, especially the **interface** spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient() class which is under System.Net.Http namespace.

```
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
        
         string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
         // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    
         Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
      }
```

Comment: the OP didn't say the target is an http server.